# How can I count adjacent cells in a matrix, and don' t get a ArrayOutOfBounds?

Tags: arrays, kotlin, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am doing a minesweeper game and I am doing a method to count the adjacent mines of the selected cell. I don't understand the output is giving to me:

The code:

```
fun counterMines() {
    var top: Int
    var right: Int
    var left: Int
    var bottom: Int
    var contador:Int=0
    var arrayCells:MutableList<Cells> = ArrayList()
    for(i in 0 until board.size){
        for(j in 0 until board[i].size){
            //top
            if (i-1>=0){
                top = i-1
            }else{
                top=0
            }
            //bottom
            if(i+1<=(n-1)) {
                bottom = i + 1
            }else{
                bottom= n - 1
            }
            //right
            if (j+1<=(n-1)){
                right = j+1
            }else{
                right=n-1
            }
            //left
            if(j-1>=0) {
                left = j - 1
            }else{
                left= 0
            }

            contador =0
            for(l in left .. right){
                for(m in top .. bottom){
                    arrayCells.add(board[l][m])
                }
            }
            for(g in 0 until arrayCells.size){
                if (arrayCells[g].getIsMine() == true) {
                    counter++
                }
            }
            board[i][j].setMines(counter);
            arrayCells.clear()
        }
    }
}
```

And it gives to me this output:

```
   a b c d e
 a 1 . . # 0 
 b 1 # 3 2 1 
 c # 3 3 # 1 
 d . . # . 1 
 e 1 . . . 0
```

For exemple the coords(row:0/col:4 =0, row:1/col:4 =1, row:4/col:0 =1), don't correspond to the output it requires. And I don't know why. Thank you

Comment: What is the "shape" of `arrayCells`, is it `arrayCells[x][y]` or `arrayCells[y][x]`? I believe you mix both. For example, `top` is created from `i` which is related to the first array dimension, but then you use `left .. right` at the first dimension.

Comment: I think you're swapping lines and columns: at the beginning `i` is the row index and `board[i]` is the column, while at the bottom you use `board[l][m]`, where `l` is the column and `m` is the row. In fact, if you transpose the numbers in the output, you get the right result as far as I can tell

Comment: but having said that, the code is quite complex to read, so I'd suggest you break down functionality in smaller, reusable functions that you can test separately. This should also help you break down the problem into smaller and simpler sub-problems

Comment: You use meaningfull names like ``top`` or ``left`` or ``contador`` and then suddenly ``i`` and ``j`` and ``l`` and ``m``. What is ``i``? What is ``m``? Can you tell it without analyzing your code? You wouldn't have had your problems if you'd used meaningful names here too, such as ``row`` and ``col`` for example! Besides, it is NOT advised to use ``l`` as a variable name.

Comment: Yes people, thats it. The fors are swapped!!! Thank you so much!!